# How to run multi for loop in Django template?

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a template in which i need to run two for loop simultanously. For example:

```
#pseudocode
{% for x in one%} and {% for y in two %}
 {{x}}, {{y}}
{% endfor %}
```

PS: The above code is pseudo. I also found a package to do it i.e. [Djnago-multiforloop](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-multiforloop/0.2.1)

Is there any other way to do it ?

### Updated!

I have a dictionary with named `objects` in python like this:

```
{<User: x>: True, <User: y>: False}
```

Now i want to use these value in my Django-template code:

```
 {% for share_user in objects %} and {% for key, value in objects.iteritems %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ share_user }}</td> 
        <td><a href="{% url share_edit type type.pk share_user.id %}">{{ value}}</a></td>
    </tr>   
{% endfor %}
```

I want to merge the two `for loop`  so that the below code in template work successfully.

Desired output:
For the first iteration:

```
x
True
```

For the second iteration:

```
Y
False
```

In my views.py:

```
 permission_obj = somemodels.objects.filter(object_id=object_id)
 for perm in permission_obj:
    s_user.append(perm.user)
    s_edit.append(perm.edit)
 objects = dict(zip(s_user,s_edit))
 extra_context = {
   'objects' : objects
    }
```

Comment: That package Django-multiforloop looks quite impressive. Is there a reason why you don't want to use that?

Comment: I don't want to use more package in my application. BTW i just wanted to know the trick if it is :)

Comment: You can do it by custom filters or tags.

Comment: @Ahsan would you please tell me how?

Comment: @AmitPal ok update your question with some values in one and two, and desire output.

Comment: @Ahsan Done! everything will be fine if we merge the for loop.

Comment: @AmitPal It will be very easy if you change the `objects` to `objects = [{<User: x>: True},{<User: y>: False}]` or `objects = [(<User: x>, True),(<User: y>, False)]`

Comment: @Ahsan According to change the objects into list. How it will be helpful for me?

Answer (score 1):

2Only you can do something like this:

```
{% for x, y in one_and_two %}
   {{x}}, {{y}}
{% endfor %}
```

If one is [1, 2, 3]
and two is [4, 5, 6]

one_and_two is [(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]

Comment: I have some like this:
***{% for x, value in obj1_and_obj.iteritems %}***

Actual in one loop i am loading values of a dictionary and from one loop i am loading form the list. Is there any error with the code?

Answer (score 0):

According to your update in question.

view.py

```
permission_obj = somemodels.objects.filter(object_id=object_id)
objects = []

for perm in permission_obj:
   objects.append({'user':perm.user,'edit':perm.edit})

 extra_context = {
   'objects' : objects
    }
```

template.html

```
{% for obj in objects %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ obj.user }}</td> 
        <td><a href="{% url share_edit type type.pk obj.user.id %}">{{ obj.edit }}</a></td>
    </tr>   
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Hey, have you checked the ***share_user.id*** in reverse of that url. That is the reason i want to do that because i also want to get the value of share_user.id , which comes from this loop ***{% for share_user in objects %}***. That's is the only reason i want to do that.

Comment: @AmitPal Sorry i forgot to change it, check it now

Answer (score 0):

If you want to iterate through 2 lists of same size you can use zip() in python 
Please check this answer for the details 
 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/14841466/9715289