# is there a way to loop over two lists simultaneously in django?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I have two list objects of the same length with complementary data i want to render is there a way to render both at the same time ie.

```
{% for i,j in table, total %} 
 {{ i }} 
 {{ j }}
{% endfor %}
```

or something similar?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Iterating through two lists in Django templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2415865/iterating-through-two-lists-in-django-templates)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

If both lists are of the same length, you can return `zipped_data = zip(table, total)` as template context in your view, which produces a list of 2-valued tuples.

Example:

```
>>> lst1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> lst2 = [1, 2, 3]
>>> zip(lst1, lst2)
[('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3)]
```

In your template, you can then write:

```
{% for i, j in zipped_data %}
    {{ i }}, {{ j }}
{% endfor %}
```

Also, take a look at Django's documentation about the `for` template tag [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/templates/builtins/#for). It mentions all possibilities that you have for using it including nice examples.

Comment: this question seemed rather easy, or im rather dum. but thanks to every one that answered!

Comment: @mike You are not dumb. All of us were at this point some time ago when learning about Python and Django. And Django's docs don't mention Python's `zip` function, so this question was definitely useful. I'm glad that I could help you. :)

Answer (score 7):

For any recent visitors to this question, [forloop.parentloop](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#for) can mimic the zipping of two lists together:

```
{% for a in list_a %}{% for b in list_b %}
    {% if forloop.counter == forloop.parentloop.counter %}
        {{a}} {{b}}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 5):

If it's just the variables `i` and `j` that you're looking at then this should work -

```
return render_to_response('results.html',
    {'data': zip(table, list)})

{% for i, j in data %}
    <tr>
        <td> {{ i }}: </td> <td> {{ j }} </td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

(credit to everyone else who answered this question)

Comment: Converting from a list to a dict and calling sorted on it will likely change the sorting order of the data.

Comment: good point, I've updated my answer to simply iterate the zip.

Answer (score 5):

Use python's zip function and zip the 2 lists together.

In your view:

```
zip(table, list)
```

In your template, you can iterate this like a simple list, and use the .0 and .1 properties to access the data from table and list, respectively.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using a dictionary (which does not guarantee any kind of sorting), use the python `zip` function on the two lists and pass it to the template.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to do this in the view - use the builtin zip function to make a list of tuples, then iterate over it in the template.

Template logic is purposely simple, anything even slightly complex should be done in the view.