# Accessing values of multiple lists using an index in Django template tags

Tags: html, django, python-3.x, django-templates

So I have three list of the same length `a`, `b` and `c` and another list `d` that are just numbers from 0 to `len(a)`. I want to display the first three lists in an html table. So I wrote:

```
{% for i in d %}

<tr>
    <td>{{a.i}}</td>
    <td>{{b.i}}</td>
    <td>{{c.i}}</td>
</tr>

{% endfor %}
```

For some reason this doesn't work but if change `i` to any number (like 0) it correctly display the first item of each list in every row. How do I use indexes in template tags to show what I want?

Comment: Likely dupe of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14841466/2337736

Comment: You're correct. Thank you!

Comment: And if you're doing this a lot or just don't want to edit your views you can create a custom template filter for zip, as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14857664/2337736